# How to create a basic project that everyone can pull, but not push

Tags: git

In my firm we are currently building a basic VS project which will be the beginning of every new project. In this project, we'll add the "good" version of the dependencies such as jquery or bootstrap.

For the moment, it is just a folder that people manually copies and start the project from it.

Would it be possible for the developpers to pull the project, and then consider it as a new git project? So that when they commit new versions, it is no more considered as new versions of the "base project"?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean like Github describes in their Duplicating a repository article: https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository

Answer (score 1):

Assuming nobody will change initial set of files, `git pull origin` should work straight forward.

To push it to different location than original, just add it as another remote location, like `git remote add origin2 https://github.com/user/repo.git`, and to block pushing to "base project", remember to remove all redundant public keys from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

The problem with that is that if it happens that two developpers make the mistake to push to origin instead of origin, the base-project will be altered with things that have nothing to do with. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want is a repository template.

To use a template just this time:

```
git init --template=/path/to/template
```

To use a template by default at whatever level you want:

```
git config {--global,--system} init.templatedir /path/to/template
```

`git init --template='' x` makes a no-frills-at-all repo in `x`.  Your template can contain anything.